# Capitalisation in "How to Generate an invoice"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000052534-how-to-generate-an-invoice

Should *invoice* be capitalized as well? Also point 2 should be reworded and the word to should be capitalized:

> You'll then be presented with your Billing and Account information. **to**
>   generate an invoice, click the date of the invoice you'd like to
>   generate, this details all account changes and updates. (Highlighted
>   below)

Comment: Invoice isn't a proper noun, and it's not at the beginning of the sentence, so there's no reason to capitalize it. It's iffy too if "Billing" or "Account" should be capitalized.

Comment: Unless you mean in the title, then it's appropriate for Invoice to be capitalized. I was just assuming you meant in the section you quoted.

Comment: @DavyM - I mean in the title since Generate was cap'ed.

Comment: That page definitely needs to be copy edited. There is also *"... will then be **dowloaded**."* (my emphasis).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Dowloaded: n. An object that has been loaded onto the Dow Jones Stock Market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.

Comment: But the "dowloaded" is still in there. And "corresponsing".